# firebase remove value causes tableview to reload with double the elements

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I have a simple notifications page on my app and I have set up friend requesting within the app, and when a notification for a friend request or message is made, it is added to the receivers messages page. When the user selects decline friend request, the alert view dismisses, but then the tableview reloads with double the items, same for the accept. I have no functions called to reload it after the click accept or decline. I have tried everything and hope I can get some help. Here is some code and photos of what is occurring. Please note that my pull() function for fetching notifications is called in the viewdidload and there are not viewdidappear of viewwillappear functions called. The pull function is a basic firebase looping fetch that puts it into the notification array.

Current code: check if it is a friend request, cancel segue message and present alert view

```
    override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String,   sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if identifier == "segueNotify" {
        let index = tableViewNotifications.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        if let friendReques = notifications[index.row].friendRequest {
   let decline = UIAlertAction(title: "Decline", style: .default, handler: { (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                if let myuid = self.uid {
                    if let key = self.notifications[index.row].key {
                        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()                       

   ref.child("users").child(myuid).child("Notifications").child(key).removeValue()

                    }
                }
   // this does not work, does the same thing :
   // self.notifications.removeAll()
             //self.tableViewNotifications.reloadData()
               //self.pull()
            })

            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(cancel)
            alert.addAction(accept)
            alert.addAction(decline)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
```

Just clicking tommy's message
[image: First]

After clicking accept/decline
[image: After clicking accept]

Answer (score 0):

I added this after both the accept and decline functions :

- self.notifications.removeAll()
- self.tableViewNotifications.reloadData()